# denied: Permission "artifactregistry.repositories.uploadArtifacts" denied on resource "projects/niveustraining/locations/us/repositories/

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-artifact-registry

denied: Permission "artifactregistry.repositories.uploadArtifacts" denied on resource "projects/niveustraining/locations/us/repositories/gcr.io" (or it may not exist)

i am getting this issues on ubuntu terminal.
please let me know if anyone know about this?
i am trying these thigns.
Log into gcloud: gcloud auth login
Configure docker: gcloud auth configure-docker europe-west1-docker.pkg.dev (make sure to specify appropriate region)

Log into gcloud: gcloud auth login
Configure docker: gcloud auth configure-docker europe-west1-docker.pkg.dev (make sure to specify appropriate region)

Comment: You have a permission error. Which IAM roles are assigned to the account that you authorized the CLI `gcloud`? Did you review the IAM roles required to push to Artifact Registry? Update your post with details.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing this issue.

So before executing docker push, I did authentication. This step is not exactly mentioned in docs but this worked for me.

```
gcloud auth print-access-token | docker login -u oauth2accesstoken --password-stdin https://us-central1-docker.pkg.dev
```

Note:- change your region.